# Paste an image from clipboard doesnt work when web application is configured thro IIS

Tags: iis, image, internet-explorer-7, c#-2.0, clipboard

Am creating a web based application using ASP.NET v2.0. I have a requirement in my project to have a control in my web page that would allow the users to enter text or copy paste image from the clipboard (say a snapshot).

In order to achieve the same I have tried using the windows clipboard class in web forms and retrieved the clipboard image and stored the same in Sql Server DB. On click of the button, the corresponding image is fetched and displayed to the end user.

All this works fine when running through IDE. When I host my web app in IIS, am not able to achieve the same. Pasting the image from the clipboard on a button click doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the windows clipboard class directly on a web application.

You could have the user copy some data from the clipboard to an input control and post that data through a postback or an AJAX.  Or you could get the data from the clipboard with a client tool like a custom ActiveX control.

My guess is that when it works through the IDE, the information is getting through a "back door".  Since everything is happening on the same system, the correct information happens to be in the Windows clip board.